# Счётчик колличества нажатий на GridView

Tags: java, android

Есть `GridView`, а в него закинут `TextView`, который я подсвечиваю через обработчик. Если пользователь нажал на `TextView`, ячейка стала красной, а если он передумал, то окно возвращается в изначальный вид. Как это реализовать?

Код:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                view.setBackgroundColor (Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });
```

Или, к примеру я закрасил ячейку в красный цвет, и при повторном нажатии тогда нужно узнать, какого она цвета, тоже хотелось бы узнать, как это сделать.

Comment: setOnTouchListener.

Comment: А для цветов - прописать сущность отдельную. Поместить эти сущности в лист и проассоциировать через некий контроллер с участками окрашиваемыми. При касании - смотрим на лист сущностей, спрашиваем их - что за цвет, спрашиваем пользователя - какой цвет назначить, если цвет у сущности такой-то; красим по ответу окрашиваемый участок и прописываем в сущность цвет. Заодно храним информацию о сцене в виде сериализованной последовательности сущностей, а не окрашиваемых элементов. Легче хранить, легче восстанавливать сцену.